# angular cli Failed to create GitHub repo. Error: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: angularjs, github-pages, angular-cli

I' trying to deploy to Github Pages using angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8)

It worked fine once (when it just asked me for my user and pass)

Now, on a different repo, it wants a token:

> In order to deploy this project via GitHub Pages, we must first create a repository for it.
>   It's safer to use a token than to use a password so you will need to create one
>   Go to the following page and click "Generate new token".
>   https://github.com/settings/tokens

When I generate a token and enter my username it always gives me this error:

> Failed to create GitHub repo. Error: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, this is after entering the github token, Failed to create GitHub repo. Error: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Comment: Are you using ssh tokens for auth with github on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Log into Github and check under Repositories to see if it was created (https://github.com/settings/repositories). Follow the instructions in the Readme.md file then try to deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

You encounter this problem if you already have a repo on your github account with the same name of your project you are trying to deploy.  I got around this problem by first deleting my repo and then executing the deploy command: `ng github-pages:deploy`

I'm guessing this is because the angular-cli always tries to create the repo first and if it fails (because it already exists), then it does not progress.

This recreates your repo with an extra branch which contains the deployed app.